# Company field when enumerating contacts through CNContactStore

Tags: swift, cncontact, cncontactstore

I'm fetching some contact fields using `CNContactStore` such as *first name* (`CNContactGivenNameKey`) and *last name* (`CNContactFamilyNameKey`) but I can't find the key for *company*.

```
let request = CNContactFetchRequest(keysToFetch: [
  CNContactGivenNameKey as NSString,
  CNContactFamilyNameKey as NSString,
])

request.sortOrder = .familyName

do {
  let store = CNContactStore()
  try store.enumerateContacts(with: request) { contact, stop in
    // ...
  }
} catch {
  print(error)
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The key is `CNContactOrganizationNameKey`.

The confusion comes from the fact that the Contacts app (in all iOS, iPadOS and macOS) use the word *company* while the key refers to it as *organization*, making it hard to find through auto-complete in Xcode, or when searching for it in Google or Stack Overflow.